# On Linux system, init.lua and/or init.vim are not sourced automatically

Tags: neovim, init, init.lua

On a [VoidLinux](https://voidlinux.org/) system my `init.lua` (or init.vim) are not being read.

```
nvim foo # init.lua not read
nvim -u ~/.config/nvim/init.lua foo # init.lua is read fine
```

The files are in the correct place:

```
❯ tree ~/.config/nvim
/home/erwin/.config/nvim/
├── init.lua
```

Using `strace` I have verified that the NeoVim binary is not even attempting to open the `init.lua` file, even though it stats the file and determines that `init.lua` exists and `init.vim` does not (ENOENT)

```
$ strace -f nvim -c ':quit' 2>&1 | grep '/init\.'

[pid  2179] readv(25, [{iov_base="e/erwin/.config/nvim/init.vim\241c\34"..., iov_len=35}, {iov_base="\n\316c|#f,\203\241f\304!/home/erwin/.config/"..., iov_len=1024}], 2) = 407
[pid  2179] statx(AT_FDCWD, ".config/nvim/init.lua", AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT, STATX_ALL, {stx_mask=STATX_ALL|STATX_MNT_ID, stx_attributes=0, stx_mode=S_IFREG|0644, stx_size=135, ...}) = 0
[pid  2179] statx(AT_FDCWD, ".config/nvim/init.vim", AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT, STATX_ALL, 0x7ffde8f874c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2179] readv(25, [{iov_base="e/erwin/.config/nvim/init.vim\241c\34"..., iov_len=35}, {iov_base="\n\316c|#f,\203\241f\304!/home/erwin/.config/"..., iov_len=1024}], 2) = 407
[pid  2179] write(26, "home/erwin/.config/nvim/init.vim"..., 410) = 410
```

None of the `$XDG_*` variables are set in a way that would change the location of `~/.config`

Answer (score 2):

### SOLUTION:

```
unset VIMINIT EXINIT MYVIMRC
nvim
```

### DISCOVERING THE SOLUTION:

I tried this on another box (with my same dotfiles) and I got the same result.

I use the [PowerLevel10K Zsh](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k) prompt theme, which looks great, but adds a TON (288 right now) extra environment variables, making it difficult to see what else may be happening with the environment.

So I used `env` to start `nvim` with an empty environment:

```
env --ignore-environment nvim
```

With an empty environment, `init.lua` was sourced automatically.

It turns out I was using `$VIMINIT` to set some basic defaults for `vi` and `vim` and neovim was reading `$VIMINIT` instead of the `init.lua` file.

I just needed to `unset VIMINIT` and `neovim` sources `init.lua` as expected.

According to NeoVim's `starting.txt`, it looks like `$EXINIT` or `$MYVIMRC` could also trigger this.